# How to removeChild on multiply tablerow's

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get this working. First I create a new `tr` and `td`, and then I want to remove it. It works great the first time, but if I have several tr's I just keep getting this error:

> main2.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at HTMLTableSectionElement.

As I said, it works great to delete the first row.

```js
function addReport(){
  addTr();
  for(var i = 0; i < reportForm.length; i++){
    if(reportForm[i].name == 'project' || reportForm[i].name == 'activity' || reportForm[i].type == 'text' || reportForm[i].name == 'note'){
      var newTd = document.createElement('td');
      newTd.textContent = reportForm[i].value;
      newTr.appendChild(newTd);
    } 
  }
  addEdit();
  report.reset();
};



function addTr(){
  newTr = document.createElement('tr');
  newTr.setAttribute('id', 'myTr');
  list.appendChild(newTr);
}

function addEdit() {
  var remove = document.createElement('td');
  remove.textContent = 'Ta bort';
  newTr.appendChild(remove);

  var edit = document.createElement('td');
  edit.textContent = 'Redigera';
  newTr.appendChild(edit);
}


/*------------------DELETE REPORT--------------------------*/
list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  list.removeChild(myTr);
});
```

Comment: `list` isn't defined in your code.

Comment: I'd recommend to solve this problem on a higher level of abstraction. Don't work with removeChild() but with something like `document.getElementById(<myID>).deleteRow(index)`.

Comment: That's more what i want. But how do i get the index? I've been trying with rowIndex but cant get it work. I want to remove that row with same index as i click.

Answer (score 0):

From just your javascript, it looks like it's trying to removing the same child (`myTr`) over and over, even after it is already removed.

Here are a couple possible solutions, depending on your exact needs:

- Assign the correct element to `myTr` before you call `list.removeChild(myTr)`
- If the child meant to be removed is always the first or last remaining one, use `list.children().first().remove()` or `list.children().last().remove()`.